# Criar um "inventário" no php

Tags: php

Estou tentando criar uma espécie de inventário no php. basicamente um programa que ao colocar certo número na tela, ele te leve ao inventário, onde você pode pegar e remover itens.
Estou tentando fazer com que o programa mostre todos os itens que estão marcados com o número 3 (número que identifica que o item está no inventário), mas não sei fazer o algoritmo a seguir no php:

```
        $itens=array('ameixa' => 2, 'abacate'=>3, 'mamão' =>1, 'maçã' =>3);
         echo'<table style="align:center;" border="1">';

         for($i=0;$i<=$itens.lengh; $i++)
         {
            if($itens[$i] == 3)
            {
            echo'<tr>
            <td>'.$itens[$i].'</td></tr>';
            }
         }
```

Comment: O sinal de comparação é == e não apenas um, que seria para setar um valor a uma variável.

Comment: Ok, mas o comando `"variável".lengh` funciona no php?

Comment: Use o`foreach` para percorrer *array* em PHP.

Comment: e como faço para ele puxar não só o número, mas o nome do array também?

Comment: Estudando como o [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php) funciona :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$itens = array('ameixa' => 2, 'abacate' => 3, 'mamão' => 1, 'maçã' => 3);

echo '<table style="align:center;" border="1">';

// Como não está explicito a posição de cada item do inventário, aqui pegamos a posição de cada um
$keys = array_keys($itens);    

// Criamos um for usando um count para contar a quantidade de itens do inventário
for ($i = 0; $i < count($itens); $i++) {
    // Definimos nessa variável o nome do itens
    $key = $keys[$i];
    // Definimos nessa variável o número que está dentro do itens
    $value = $itens[$key];
    // Fazemos a comparação pra ver se o número é igual a 3
    if ($value == 3) {
        // Então imprimimos o nome do item
        echo '<tr><td>'.$key.'</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Realmente, a melhor resposta que eu poderia ter. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma fácil de percorrer um array é usando o foreach

```
$itens=array('ameixa' => 2, 'abacate'=>3, 'mamão' =>1, 'maçã' =>3);
echo'<table style="align:center;" border="1">';

//Um exemplo:
//Na primeira interação '$key' seria a ameixa e o '$value' seria 2 
foreach($itens as $key => $value){
    //Aqui é verifica e imprime o item
    if($value == 3) echo '<tr><td>'.$key.'</td></tr>';
}
```